# Circular reference with keyof and never

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble understanding some typescript behavior in regards to circular references for types.

```js
type NonEmptyObject<T> = keyof T extends never ? never : T

type Base = { [key: PropertyKey]: Nested }; // I'm using this instead of Record to avoid a circular reference.
type NonEmptyBase = NonEmptyObject<Base>;
type Nested = string | NonEmptyBase;
```

`Type alias 'NonEmptyBase' circularly references itself.ts(2456)`

`Type alias 'Nested' circularly references itself.ts(2456)`

If I switch to generics, everything works fine. But this looks wrong and feels even more circularly mixed up.

```js
type Base<T extends Base<T>> = { [key: PropertyKey]: Nested<T> };
type NonEmptyBase<T extends Base<T>> = NonEmptyObject<T>;
type Nested<T extends Base<T>> = string | NonEmptyBase<T>;
```

Why is this and how can I achieve the desired outcome without generics?

Comment: would `type Nested = string | Base` be okay for you? Or do you necessarily need the nested ones nonempty? I'm really unsure about your `NonEmptyBase`. Your generic doesn't make any sense in here, since you are not passing any generic types there, but rather a `Base`, which's key are `PropertyKey`, so basically `NonEmptyBase` is the same as `Base`

Comment: I do need the `Base` to be nonempty. The reasoning is that I don't want to be able to pass an empty object into the function using this type. I have tried extending the generic to `NonEmptyObject<T extends object>`, but unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is due to circular references in your type definitions. TypeScript is unable to resolve these circular references when defining type aliases directly.

In your initial code, the NonEmptyBase type refers to NonEmptyObject, and Base refers to Nested, while Nested also refers to NonEmptyBase. This circular reference creates an error.

To achieve the desired outcome without using generics, you can use interfaces instead of type aliases.

As per this link - [1]: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28748

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But circular references are not an issue per se. Consider `type A = string | B; type B = { [key: string]: A };`. I am using something similar in a recursive pattern and it works fine. The question I have asked seems to have something to do with either `keyof` or `never`, or maybe both.

Comment: @KorbenDose But circular references are the crux of the problem.  Sometimes TS can deal with them, in certain constructs, if it decides to defer the evaluation.  One way to defer evaluation is to use an `interface` instead of a type alias for `Base` (as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WY2Gxw)). Do you require an answer to walk explicitly through the compiler's type checking algorithm to show how, at every step, it keeps recursing instead of deferring?  This is possible to do but requires more effort than I imagine someone will want to expend.

Comment: I have tried the interface approach, and for some reason VS code sometimes accepts it and sometimes randomly marks it as a circular reference. No clue what is going on, but I will just assume that this is not reliably possible with typescript.

Comment: "for some reason VS code sometimes accepts it and sometimes randomly marks it as a circular reference" without a [mre] I'm not sure what to say, but since you accepted this answer (even though it apparently doesn't work for you) then I guess we're done here more or less.  Oh well, good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I settled with a different approach. I didn't want to waste anybody's time when I can do it differently. Thanks anyway!